# Extract characters after a symbol in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table List shown below:

```
+------+-------------------------------------+
| Code |                name                 |
+------+-------------------------------------+
| A001 | ABBOTT_1000000                      |
| A002 | AGCO_1000001                        |
| A003 | ALFA LAVAL_1000002                  |
| A004 | ALSTOM POWER INDIA LIMITED_1000003  |
| A005 | AMERICAN BUREAU OF SHIPPING_1000004 |
+------+-------------------------------------+
```

I need to update the table extracting the characters present after _ in name and replace them in code column. like this.

```
+---------+-------------------------------------+
|  Code   |                name                 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
| 1000000 | ABBOTT_1000000                      |
| 1000001 | AGCO_1000001                        |
| 1000002 | ALFA LAVAL_1000002                  |
| 1000003 | ALSTOM POWER INDIA LIMITED_1000003  |
| 1000004 | AMERICAN BUREAU OF SHIPPING_1000004 |
+---------+-------------------------------------+
```

This is has to be done in sql server 2012. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `SUBSTRING` in following:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
Code NVARCHAR(60),
Name NVARCHAR(60)
)
INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES
('A001','ABBOTT_1000000'                      ),
('A002','AGCO_1000001'                        ),
('A003','ALFA LAVAL_1000002'                  ),
('A004','ALSTOM POWER INDIA LIMITED_1000003'  ),
('A005','AMERICAN BUREAU OF SHIPPING_1000004' )
```

**QUERY**

```
UPDATE #MyTable
SET Code = SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('_', Name) + 1, LEN(Name))
```

**TESTING**

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTable    
DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Code    Name
1000000 ABBOTT_1000000
1000001 AGCO_1000001
1000002 ALFA LAVAL_1000002
1000003 ALSTOM POWER INDIA LIMITED_1000003
1000004 AMERICAN BUREAU OF SHIPPING_1000004
```

**SQL FIDDLE**

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8d417/2)</kbd>**

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
with cte as
(
select substring(name,charindex('_',name)+1,len(name)) as ext_str,*
from yourtable
)
update cte set code = ext_str
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RIGHT` together with `CHARINDEX`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e73c2/1/0)

```
UPDATE tbl
    SET Code = RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - CHARINDEX('_', Name))
WHERE CHARINDEX('_', Name) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE <table>
SET name = STUFF(name, 1, CHARINDEX('_', name), '')
WHERE name like '%[_]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: 
First, you select the number that you want to place as code

```
select substr(name,-1,7) from table_name
```

After this, you can update the table.So,The complete statement will be :

```
update table_name t set t.code = (select substr(name,-1,7) from table_name where code = t.code);
```